# MongoDB converting from int32 to double itself

Tags: javascript, mongodb, casting, mongo-shell, studio3t

I am getting a weird problem when I run in shell for mongoDB.
My collection structure is like below in mongoDB.The type of ServiceList items must be integer.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56565"), 
    "Contact" : "", 
    "Email" : "", 
    "AppList" : [

        {
            "Code" : "", 
            "Usage" : NumberInt(542),    
            "LicenceType" : "Monthly", 
            "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2015-07-29T06:15:20.520+0300"), 
            "ServiceList" : [
                1,5,8
            ]

        }
    ]

}
```

My aim to run this code is converting Usage type from int32 to int64.It works fine.When I run the code below. something weird occours, and the type of the items inside `AppList.ServiceList` is converted to `double`  from `int32` itself.

```
db.CustomerInfo.find({}).forEach( function (item) {
 if(item.AppList != undefined){

   item.AppList.forEach(function (x){
      x.Usage = NumberLong(x.Usage);

    });
           db.CustomerInfo.save(item);
 }
});
```

and it seems like this,

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56565"), 
    "Contact" : "", 
    "Email" : "", 
    "AppList" : [

        {
            "Code" : "", 
            "Usage" : NumberLong(542),    
            "LicenceType" : "Monthly", 
            "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2015-07-29T06:15:20.520+0300"), 
            "ServiceList" : [
                1.0,5.0,8.0
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

How can I solve this problem ?

MongoDB version:3.4.9
MongoShell version:v3.4.9

Comment: Looks like a mongo issue to me. Didn't happen on 3.2

Comment: Have you tried it without putting the conversion code? Just read, (maybe add a flag `processed:true`) and save. Just to see if mongo is messing up something while saving

Comment: yeah I tried it, but it is still converting to Double :/

Comment: Then it must be a mongo issue. Try updating to latest version, I think its 3.4.14 right now

Comment: try to use NumberInt in order to be sure about the types are not being converted